# V8 WasmModuleBuilder return multiple values from functions

Tags: javascript, v8, was

I am trying to construct a wasm function using WasmModuleBuilder from V8:

```
var builder = new WasmModuleBuilder();
builder.addMemory(5, 5, false);
builder.addFunction("func", {params: [125,125], results: [125,125]});
builder.functions[0].addBody([
                       kExprGetLocal,
                       0,
                     kExprGetLocal,
                      1
          ]);
          x = builder.instantiate()
          for (f in x.exports) {
                console.log(x.exports[f](0.5, 0.5))
            }
```

I am getting an exception:

asm decoding failed: return count of 2 exceeds internal limit of 1 @+15

How can I return multiple values? Suggestions of other ways to create wasm functions from javascript code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *How can I return multiple values?* use an array

Comment: I don't understand your answer,can you give an example using wasm opcodes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the WasmModuleBuilder has not yet been adjusted to support multiple values. You may want to file an issue.